# attr_accessor won't work when used in procs

Tags: ruby, attr-accessor

I wrote the following snippet to download some files I need to.

```
require 'open-uri'

MEGABYTE = 1024.0 * 1024.0

def bytes_to_megabytes(bytes)
  bytes / MEGABYTE
end

class Downloader
  class << self
    attr_accessor :size

    def get(resource)
      open(resource,
         content_length_proc: proc do |t|
           size = bytes_to_megabytes(t).round
           puts "Total size is: #{size}"
         end,
         progress_proc: proc do |step| 
           # size won't print here!
           puts "Downloading #{bytes_to_megabytes(step).round} out of #{size}"
         end ) 
    end
  end
end
```

Problem is the total size won't print on the last line even though it has already been set in `content_length_proc`.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> even though it has already been set in `content_length_proc`

No, it hasn't been set. You set a local variable `size` there, not the accessor. Rookie mistake. Change to this:

```
self.size = bytes_to_megabytes(t).round
```

Comment: BTW, this (“missing `self`”) would be probably the first rubocop suggestion ever I could consider helpful (if rubocop bothered to suggest it.)

Comment: @mudasobwa: how would it know? :shrug:

Comment: You gotta be kidding. Assignment to a local variable that shadows the instance variable? Nearly impossible to discover, yeah :)

Comment: @mudasobwa: you're joking, but it IS so. Impossible [to do with any kind of certainty] without actually running the code.

Comment: “to do with any kind of certainty”—there are numbers besides `0`, `1` and `∞` ;) It should not be _certain_ for dynamically assigned, coming from `instance_eval` etc. It should be as easy as: `warn if scope_contains_instance_variable && local_variable_shadows_it`.

Comment: @mudasobwa what scope? Scope doesn't exist until code is running (particularly, scope of the instance variables). And you're saying "instance variable" again. You must be aware that the shadowing happens to the method, not the variable. So why you keep using this word, is beyond me. :)

Comment: Shadowing happens to the method, indeed, I was to say “attr_writer and/or attr_accessor is defined for the instance variable with the same name” but was too lazy to type all that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169877/discussion-between-sergio-tulentsev-and-mudasobwa).